# How to get_absolute_url with domain in Django template?

Tags: django

So I am struggling a bit, with something that logically seems so simple but due to my limited understanding of Django I am not sure where to look and how to formulate a solution.

Basically I have a Blog app set up and it shows the complete(all the content including disqus discussion) latest post on the home page. The post has a further link to the posts own page as well. I have set up Disqus and need to get some key information to use for the `disqus_url` and `disqus_identifier`. I have set up the model as follows with a method for `get_absolute_url` as follows:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog.views.renderBlog',args=[str(self.id),str(self.slug)])
```

My view is set up as follows:

```
def renderBlog(request,postid=1,slug=None):
    template = 'blog_home.html'

    if(postid == 1 and slug == None):
        post = Post.objects.latest('date_created')
    else:
        post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug, id=postid)

    data = {
            'post':post,
        }

    return render(request, template, data)
```

As you can see the view is set up to handle both URL's as follows:

```
    url(r'^$', 'renderBlog', name='blogHome'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<postid>\d{1,4})/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'renderBlog', name='blogPostPage'),
```

In my template I am setting `disqus_identifier = '{{ post.get_absolute_url }}'` and I am hardcoding the domain portion in the meantime as `disqus_url = 'http://127.0.0.1{{ post.get_absolute_url }}';.`. Same goes for the comment count `<a href="" data-disqus-identifier`.

I dont like doing things in a hackish manner, what would be the best method for me to get the full absolute url. I have looked at request.get_absolute_uri but am not sure on how to actually use it to get what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way I like to do it is configure a `context_processor`:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

def base_context_processor(request):
     return {
         'BASE_URL': "http://%s" % Site.objects.get_current().domain
     }
     # or if you don't want to use 'sites' app
     return {
         'BASE_URL': request.build_absolute_uri("/").rstrip("/")
     }
```

in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'path.to.base_context_processor',
    ...
)
```

(In newer versions of Django, modify `context_processors` under `TEMPLATES`, `OPTIONS` instead.)

then in templates:

```
<a href="{{ BASE_URL }}{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">Object Name</a>
```

Another solution would be to use `request.build_absolute_uri(location)`, but then you would have to create a template tag that takes a `request` object and a `location` or an object that has `get_absolute_uri` method. Then you would be able to use it templates like that: `{% get_full_uri request=request obj=post %}`. Here is [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) on how to write custom tags.

Comment: Note that this `BASE_URL` won't work for https sites, or URLs with a port component. Better to use `"BASE_URL": request.build_absolute_uri("/").rstrip("/")`, which will handle all of those situations correctly.

Comment: If both https and http are used I would just just omit the scheme altogether in this way: `'BASE_URL': "//%s" % request.get_host()`

Comment: Depending on the context, that could defeat the purpose of an absolute URL (ie, because it becomes scheme-relative).

Comment: @DavidWolever You are right, it does depend on a situation, your solution would probably be better when mixed schemas are used.

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty old but I think its still relevant.
To `get_absolute_url` with domain in Django template you can do the following:

```
<li><a href="{% if request.is_secure %}https://{% else %}http://{% endif %}{{ request.get_host }}{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">Home</a></li>
```

First check if the request is https or not and then get the request of the host and pass the absolute url.

This way you will get full URL with domain in Django template.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I'm not sure the best answer provided is the correct one.

You should just use

```
<a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}"></a>
```

as the Django docs point out.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

The url provided comes with the domain as well.

Regards